# Thread com loading em python

Tags: python

Estou tentando executar duas *threads* onde uma é uma animação de *loading*, e a outra um print, porém ao terminar de executar a *thread* **work** que é o print, o *loading* continua rodando, gostaria que ele finalizasse assim que o print fosse realizado

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

done = False

#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')

def work():
    print('\nexecutado, finalizando o loading')
    #long process here
    done = True

load = threading.Thread(target=animate)
load.start()
worker = threading.Thread(target=work)
worker.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua lógica está certa, na maneira de tentar finalizar uma Thread utilizando outra, mas existe um erro substancial no código, quando você indica dentro da função work que o `done = True` ele será `True` apenas dentro da função, quando fui rodar seu código, ao debugar utilizando `prints` básicos percebe-se que ao entrar na função work ela(a variável), fica verdadeira, mas ao sair retorna pra Falsa. Então o que deve ser feito é, fazer a função `work()` retornar o valor de `done = True`, e fora da função consumir esse valor.

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

done = False

#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')

def work():
    print('\nexecutado, finalizando o loading')
    #long process here

    done = True

    return done # Aqui você retorna o valor

load = threading.Thread(target=animate)
load.start()
worker = threading.Thread(target=work)

done = work()  #Aqui você recebe o valor True

worker.start()
```

Não trabalhei nada no código, só duas linhas, então só com essa adequação ele não terá a saída que desejas, mas pelo menos funcionou quanto a finalizar uma thread com outra thread.

Comment: Muito obrigado irmão, não estava enxergando o erro! :)

Comment: Beleza mano! Quando coisas assim acontecem, ou você vai conferindo o funcionamento usando debugger da sua IDE, ou vai testando o funcionamento do código linha por linha, inicialmente printando todos os estados duvidosos.

Comment: valeu pela dica!!